# The judge said wrong answer in cAPS lOCK

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

everyone. In the question [cAPS lOCK](https://codeforces.com/gym/338178/problem/D) on Codeforces, the judge said the wrong answer for test case number 3, i.e, 'cAPSlOCK'. Now, from reading the question and the following conditions being given:

"Let's consider that a word has been typed with the Caps lock key accidentally switched on, if:

a) either it only contains uppercase letters; b) or all letters except for the first one are uppercase."

taking the above conditions into consideration, 'cAPSlOCK' should change to 'CapsLock' as apart from 'c' not all the words are lowercase, i.e, 'l'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

string str;
cin>>str;
int count(0);
int len = str.length();
bool flag = true;
char first{str[0]};

if(isupper(first))
{
    for(int i = 1; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(islower(str[i]))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}

count = count;


if (count == len - 1){flag = false;}
count = 0;

if(len = 1 && islower(first)){flag = true;}

while(flag)
{
for(auto& i : str)
    {
        if(isupper(i))
        {
            i = tolower(i);
        }
        else if (islower(i))
        {
            i = toupper(i);
        }
    }
break;
}

cout<<str<<endl;

}
```

So, my code converts 'cAPSlOCK' to 'CapsLock', however the desired answer is 'cAPSlOCK'

I highly appreciate anyone's input here.

Comment: Do you know **why** your program answers CapsLock?

Comment: Caps Lock is clearly two words.  Is cAPSlOCK one word or two?

Comment: fwiw, the line `count = count;` does nothing and can be removed. The loop with `while(flag)` is not using `flag` and always breaks after the first iteration, you should replace it with `if (flag)`. `int len = str.length();` is also unnecessary, keeping track of the size seperate from the string is just an opportunity for mistakes, better use `str.length()` directly (unless `len` is the initial lenght and the actual lenght changes later, but thats not the case). Similar for `char first{str[0]};`, its not really needed, you can use `str[0]` directly

Comment: @user253751 Yes, that is the intended output, I should have written it more carefully. I don't understand why cAPSlOCK should be left as it is.

Comment: @user10489 Is it though... It is clearly a single word.

Comment: you start with `flag = true` and only set it to false when the count of lower case letters does match. Thats the wrong logic. Try to see what happens in that part of the code with a debugger

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thank You... ```count=count;``` was a left over piece of code from my last try, I also posted it from my mobile so I couldn't see it, sorry about that. I made the above two changes thank you. 

I have kept len and first as it makes it easy for me to debug, I am just learning so I will keep the advices in mind. 

Could you shed some light on why cAPSlOCK should be kept as cAPSlOCK

Comment: Because it is one word and doesn't fit the rules for a word that should be changed.

Comment: @GuruRandapa Because it doesn't fit condition (a) and it doesn't fit condition (b). It says "do this if that" but "that" is not true so you shouldn't do "this". It isn't all uppercase, and it isn't all uppercase apart from the first letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use a debugger to see what the code does. Using a debugger you will see that for input `cAPSlOCK` your code...

Initializes

```
bool flag = true;
```

checks if the first character is uppercase (it is not)

```
if(isupper(first))
```

checks if `count` equals number of characters -1 (count is still `0`)

```
if (count == len - 1){flag = false;}
```

and then uses a condition that has a typo

```
if(len = 1 && islower(first)){flag = true;}
```

`len = 1` is assignment not comparison. There should be a compiler warning for that. Do not ignore compiler warnings! However, even fixing that condition won't change the final result, because `flag` is still `true` anyhow.

Eventually it transforms upper to lower and lower to upper case letters:

```
while(flag) 
      ....
```

---

Your logic is wrong. When the condition says:

> a) either it only contains uppercase letters; b) or all letters except for the first one are uppercase.

Then you should only transform the characters when those conditions do apply. You should not start with `flag = true` and then check the conditions.

Your code would be more readable if you used functions. I suggest to write two functions for each of the condition:

```
 bool only_uppercase_letters(const std::string& input) {
        //...
 }

 bool first_lower_and_all_others_upper_case(const std::string& input) {
        //..
 }
```

And a third function to transform the letters:

```
 void transform_letters(std::string& input) {
        // ...
 }
```

Then `main` can be much simpler:

```
int main() {
    std::string inp;
    std::cin >> inp;
    if (only_uppercase_letters(inp) || first_lower_and_all_others_upper_case(inp)) {
         transform_letters(inp);
    }
    std::cout << inp;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! The advices are very helpful... However if I may ask from the problem do you think 'cAPlOCK' should change to 'cAPSlOCK' or 'CapsLock'...

The answer provided by the test case is 'cAPSlOCK'...

Comment: @GuruRandapa `cAPSlOCK` does not a) only contain uppercase letters and not b)  all letters except for the first one are uppercase, so it should not be changed at all as I understand the task